# get largest between two input fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following input field for DOB.

```
<div class="po.pependent">
        <input type="text", class="zm-textbox dob-input-mask" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />,
         <input type="text", class="zm-textbox dob-input-mask" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/></div>
```

So if  enter dob 11/12/1999 and 11/12/1997 the function paymentForm.computeAge return 17 and 19.

Now in JS i am trying to get the value of these to Dob convert them  and get the highest age among the two dob entered.

```
$(".po.pependent:visible input.zm-textbox.dob-input-mask:visible")
        .each(function() {
            paymentForm.computeAge($(this).val())
    })
```

This `paymentForm.computeAge`  return the calculated age from the given dob date comparing with current system date.

Comment: What is `paymentForm`? What does `computeAge` do? How do you even get the resulting array having no return statements at all?

Comment: If you're using a particular library, please include a tag for it. This code makes no sense as plain javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `Math.max`. Below are 2 ways of doing it:

```js
console.log(Math.max(17, 19));

var ageArray = [17, 19]
var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, ageArray.map(Number));
console.log(max_of_array)
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate posts. If you know the solution, and you think its basic, please look for similar posts and mark them as dupe. Its wrong to answer a dupe

Comment: I tried to do it it retruns NAN

Comment: @PrabinPoudel - the code in the answer does not return NaN ... perhaps you need `var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, ageArray.map(Number));` instead

Comment: In that case, you aren't getting an array. You need to share what you are getting.

Comment: @MilanChheda - it could be an array ... of strings ... which is what `$(this).val()` will always be

Comment: Possible @JaromandaX. Prabin, check again using `ageArray.map(Number)` and also, hope its not an multi-array.

Comment: Possible? I'd say it's more than likely that an array derived from `$(this).val()` is an array of strings ... it won't be anything other than strings in fact

Comment: You are right. `$(this).val()` returns a string. @PrabinPoudel - Did you tried the updated code?

Comment: var a=$(".po.pependent:visible input.zm-textbox.dob-input-mask:visible").each(function() {console.log(paymentForm.computeAge($(this).val()))}); I get following output
17
19
undefined

Comment: and then var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, a.map(Number));
console.log(max_of_array)
i get 1
indefiened

Comment: `each` doesn't returns a value. You cannot have `var a = `

Comment: when i log$(".po.pependent:visible input.zm-textbox.dob-input-mask:visible").each(function() {$(this).val()});
i get [<input type="text", class="zm-textbox dob-input-mask"  id="dob0"placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />,
         <input type="text", class="zm-textbox dob-input-mask" id="dob1"placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/>] as ouput

Comment: i need the value of those #dob0 and #dob1 and get the highest from them

Comment: Its unclear. Create a working JSFiddle and update in your question.

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: ok so finally i am able to solve it ,,just need to delcare a temp araay and push all dob and get the max value as milan recommended

Answer (score -1):

Once you get your array, you can pass it to `Math.max.apply()` like I have done here with this example array.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, numbers))
console.log(Math.min.apply(null, numbers))
```

Comment: If this is the ideal solution, please choose to close it as dupe